# How to make an arrow pointing down after a section in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, polyline

I want to make a down arrow on the bottom of a `<section>` element. It should be in the middle of the bottom. But unfortunately I have not found any methods how to do this with css. And I can't figure it out myself.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="down-btn">
 <svg class="down-btn-img">
  <polyline points="0,0 50,50 100,0" />
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Try editing your `svg` to `<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the thing with margins and I attached it to the bottom with `bottom: 0`

```
.down-btn  {
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
min-width: 30px;
margin: 0px calc(50vw - 15px);
}
```

Comment: Put this in your question, as an "EDIT (ANSWER):" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
.down-arrow {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid red;
}
```

---

### Or this

HTML:

```
<section style="background: green; border-color: green;">Your section</section>
```

CSS:

```
    section {
        margin: 50px;
        padding: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }
   section:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
       top: 100%;
       left: 50px;
       border-top: 50px solid green;
       border-top-color: inherit; 
       border-left: 50px solid transparent;
       border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    }
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/taaGc/1/)

Comment: I tried that before but it makes a solid triangle and i want just the left and right border of a triangle. The svg arrow already looks good the only thing is that it is not where it should be.

Comment: Manipulate the colors.

Comment: neither of those solutions are really working because the first one shows a solid triangle (I tried manipulating the colors but it didn't work). The second one doesn't show anything at all, just the Inspector shows that the `:after` element is below the background image.

Comment: Then add a z-index. You are looking for a 100% solution here, we've gotten as far as getting the arrow facing down for you - now you try to research a little and figure the rest out. That way you learn something. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a rotated pseudo-element. No borders required and it updates based on the background color of your section.

You can even make it responsive by using `viewport units`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
  position: relative;
}
section::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  left: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RPBWwx)